# Canvas drawing doesn't work in external .js file

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

My script works when it is included in the html file, but when I move it to an external .js file, canvas doesn't draw.

this is my html file:

```
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <title>Reveal RGB Values</title>
        <form action='/' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
            <h1>Select file to upload:</h1>
            <br>
            <input type='file' name='file'>
            <input type='submit' value='submit'>
        </form>
        {% if status == 'uploaded'%}
        <h1>There will be a photo here</h1>
        <canvas id="frame"></canvas>
        <canvas id= "solution_frame"></canvas>
        <div id="solution"></div>
        {% endif %}

        <script type = text/javascript src="{{ url_for('static', filename='script.js') }}"></script>
    </body>
```

In the external .js file,  I have two canvases that successfully get built (I can see empty blanks that match the sizes)

```
var frame = document.getElementById('frame');
frame.width = 800;
frame.height = 600;
var context = frame.getContext('2d');

var solution_frame = document.getElementById('solution_frame');
var solution_context = solution_frame.getContext('2d');
solution_frame.width = 25;
solution_frame.height = 25;
```

but I cannot draw the image

```
    function draw_image(){
        base_image = new Image();
        // yay! jinja works here too.
        var image_url = '{{img_url}}';
        base_image.src = image_url;
        base_image.onload = function(){
            //context.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0);
            scale_to_fit(this);
        }
    }
    draw_image();

function scale_to_fit(img){
    //get the scale
    var scale = Math.min(frame.width/img.width, frame.height/img.height);
    var x = (frame.width/2) - (img.width/2) * scale;
    var y = (frame.height/2) - (img.height/2) * scale;
    context.drawImage(base_image,x,y,img.width*scale, img.height*scale);
```

I found a similar post that suggested me to add this

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',draw_image,false);
```

saying the script is acting before the canvas is fully loaded, but it doesn't seem to be the issue.

Can anyone see where I'm possibly going wrong? Thanks ahead

EDIT!: It just occurred to me that the issue might be related to retrieving the image source location with Jinja?

Comment: Does anything come up in the debugger console? You should have the debugger open and have enabled the "pause on exceptions" pause icon on stop sign looking icon, in the Sources tab.

Comment: @doug65536 It seems like my problem is not html/js related at all. I am using Jinja to retrieve the image location from the server, and Jinja doesn't serve to that external js file. It seems to me that function needs to be kept in the html file.

Comment: There is no difference between a `script` tag with content and and an empty `script` tag with a `src` pointing to a file with the same content.

Comment: You can check what content that script request is getting by looking at the Network tab in the debugger and examining the response. You may have to reload/recreate the issue after bringing up the Network tab though - sometimes it won't capture that stuff unless you are looking at it on reload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It seems like my problem is not html/js related at all. I am using Jinja to retrieve the image location from the server, and Jinja doesn't serve to that external js file. It seems to me that function needs to be kept in the html file.

That's correct.  Jinja doesn't run any processing on statically included assets.

I see two ways around your problem.

Either hard code the URL in `script.js`:

```
var image_url = '/path/to/image'
```

Or remove that line from the `draw_image` function and set that JS variable in the template, prior to including `script.js`:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  const image_url = {{img_url}};
</script>

<script type='text/javascript' src="{{ url_for('static', filename='script.js') }}"></script>
```

Comment: This makes sense, but for some reason, I can't get two script tags (one in the html page, one referencing the external .js file) to work. As soon as I add the second tag referencing the external file (even when the file empty and all the working code is still in the html script tag), the script stops working.

Comment: well it worked once I changed the order of the scripts! Thanks again!